# WWAN and 802.11?

Tags: c++, embedded

coding with C++ for WWAN and 802.11, is it complicated in an embedded environment?

thanks

Comment: You will have to provide a lot more information, such as OS, compiler, platform, etc.  In general, however, it will likely boil down to what kind of drivers/libraries you get from your hardware vendor.

Comment: Oh I see.  The OS mostly on Windows Mobile, but regarding to drivers or libraries I don't know.  I never done any networking programming before so not sure whether it's complicated..  But thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

here's an answer as specific as the question: no